# Radio button left blank not giving validation message

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a aspx page and CS code. I have two radio buttons YES and NO. On check of YES the textbox is visible and on Check of NO the textbox is invisible. When I don't put any value in the textbox, when I checked the radio button. It doesn't give me validation error. I'm handling that validation through CS code. Please see the js fiddle.

JS fiddle: - "http://jsfiddle.net/BaxJe/"

Also please see the button click code  for your reference: -

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    SendMail();

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        if (radiobtnIsCustomer.Checked && txt_custId.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            div_errorMsg.InnerText = "Please enter your Customer Id.";
            return;
        }

    }
    if (!CaptchaControl1.IsValid)
    {
        lblCaptchaError.Text = "Invalid Captcha";
    }

    Response.Redirect("ThankYou_AgriBusiness.html");
    Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
    newCustomer.IsExistingCustomer = radiobtnIsCustomer.Checked;
    newCustomer.ExistingCustomerId = txt_custId.Text;
}
```

Please let me know where I am getting stucked, so that I am able to detect why my validation message is not coming.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble with the jsFiddle presumably because its an aspx page. But instead of

"txt_custId.Text == string.Empty" 
 
I would try  
 
"String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_custId.Text)"

Comment: (radiobtnIsCustomer.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_custId.Text))

like this ??

Comment: it's not working, the form is still getting submitted.

Comment: Ok a bit of a shot in the dark but I believe Page.IsValid is not not being met so the checking if the textbox is empty is not even being reached. I believe you must cause the validation first by either putting the line "Page.Validate()" above the "if (page.isvalid)" line or set your buttons "causesValidation" to true.